# is it possible to forget how to pronounce a phoneme that exists in ones native language?

Tags: pronunciation, native-language

now I know this might seem like a strange question (I'm not sure if I'm using the correct tags) but hear me out.

I'm a native speaker of the Georgian language(a Kartvelian Language) who's been living in France for almost 4 years.

Throughout all these years I had no problems with Pronounciation in Georgian, up until I started trying my best to pronounce the glottal stop /ʔ/, eventually I managed to pronounce something like a glottal stop but after that I started having problems Pronouncing the /h/ sound in my native language, one day I was listening to a tajik-persian song and then tried to pronounce a word in that song which had the sound /h/ in it, my /h/ sounded pretty inaudible and similar to /χ/, previously I had no problems with pronouncing /h/, I've been struggling to pronounce /h/ and sometimes distinguishing it from /χ/ ever since then.

though when speaking Georgian, I don't Pronounce /h/ jn words like ჰქვია (hkvia) ჰგავს (hgavs) ჰყავს (hq'avs), though I used to pronounce those h's back when I had no problems with Pronouncing the /h/,

when speaking English and Georgian I try my best to pronounce it, thankfully most of time I can pronounce it as long I don't relax my mouth, because then it'll sound like /χ/, and as long as the /h/ isn't located in the aforementioned clusters ( and alike) and in a word-final position.

and to specify, my level of French is really basic, I wasn't able to attend my French classes due to the pandemic and other personal stuff.

in short: is it possible to forget how to pronounce a phoneme that exists in ones native language?

I hope I was clear, sorry if I made any mistakes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is fairly unlikely, assuming that you fully acquired and maintained the language into adulthood (young children who stop speaking a language may completely lose the language). You should consider the possibility that in your native dialect [ჰქვია](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%83%B0%E1%83%A5%E1%83%95%E1%83%98%E1%83%90) is actually ქვია without *h*. There is also evidence that [ჰგავს](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%83%B0%E1%83%A7%E1%83%90%E1%83%95%E1%83%A1) is not just "misspelled" as გავს without *h*, it is [pronounced that way](https://forvo.com/word/%E1%83%B0%E1%83%A7%E1%83%90%E1%83%95%E1%83%A1/#ka) (by the first speaker).

In fact, Robins & Waterson in their classic article on Georgian phonetics notes that *h* "is rare and perhaps confined to
exclamations and loanwords in present-day Georgian", and always is followed by a vowel. In other words, *h* in Georgian may be similar to *h* in French – a grapheme that doesn't correspond to an actual sound, but which used to exist.

Comment: Yeah I've fully acquired the language, have been speaking for 16 years of my Life, you I speak kartlian dialect of Tbilisi, yeah I Pronounce ჰქვია without  h.                          though when I to pronounce h itself, it has almost no aspiration, [it sounds like this](https://voca.ro/12CkQrKXBcCi), thank you for your answer! it seems like the situation wasn't as bad as Thought it would be.